# Alert "This page was unable to display google maps element." javascript error "RefererDeniedMapError"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting this alert message in one of my sites that uses Google Maps JavaScript API v3:

"This page was unable to display google maps element. See the terms of service"

And in the javascript console this error:
"RefererDeniedMapError"

I searched in internet and its seems to be a new bug, I only found reports in this month (June 2015).
It seems to be a domain specific problem, because the same code works in others domains.

In my case the web page were working without an API key. After this error I generated and added an API key to my code, but it doesn't solve the problem. 
In the https://console.developers.google.com/ doesn't appear any useful information. The quota of map loads is OK, but when I load the web page the map loads are not counted (probably because the error).

Does anyone has a clue about how to solve the problem?

Comment: Here's a [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/troubleshooting_auth) regarding your issue and maps issue in general. Hope you find your answer here.

Comment: Also a [**pre-launch checklist**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/prelaunch_checklist) that might help you see if you missed anything.

Comment: I had this problem before and got it works by enabling "Google Maps Javascript API" manually.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message, and realized I  replaced with below one

```
<script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message, and realized I needed to remove `"signin=true"` from the google maps call.